# Отчества от имён Захар и Захария

Tags: словообразование

Согласно [этому](http://www.e-reading.club/chapter.php/71928/24/Pashalov_-_Udivitel'naya_etimologiya.html) источнику (в ссылке с похожим содержанием написано, что это составлено по материалам Справочника личных имён народов РСФСР 1987 г.), отчества от Захара и Захарии чуть-чуть различаются: Захар**о**вич и Захар**ие**вич соответственно. Как вы считаете, действительно правильно делать это различие?

Я, конечно, понимаю, что сейчас Захариями вряд ли кто-то называет, да и просто Захарами редко, поэтому сейчас это не очень актуально. Но ведь есть другие поколения с такими именами, отчествами, и поэтому интересно узнать, как правильно и как тогда писали эти отчества.

P. S. Интересно также, было ли, скажем, до революции полным только имя Захария, а Захарами только в жизни называли тех же Захарий, или и в паспорте писали и так, и эдак. **Но это если кто знает,** а так я боюсь, что, может, выхожу за рамки допустимых тем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имён было (есть) не два, а три: Захар, Захарий и Захария.

Поэтому в Вашем вопросе ошибка: непонятно, о какой форме имени (одного и того же - "помнящий Яхве", "помнящий Господа", "Господь вспомнил"; историческая последовательность их обратная - Захария, Захарий, Захар) идёт речь.

От них образуются такие отчества: от Захара - Захарович, от Захария и Захарии одинаковые - Захарьевич (предпочтительно), Захариевич (допустимо).

И конечно правильно делать эти различия.

Моего деда звали Арсен, а в батюшкин юбилей ему (папе) надарили подарков с такой гравировкой: Арсеновичу (что единственно верно), Арсеньевичу и даже Арсентьевичу, -

ну и куда это годится?!

Первый Захария - пророк - родился во время Вавилонского плена (то есть до 539 года до н. э.); форма имени Захарий - уже наша эра; Захар, опрощённая форма, - современное нам имя (конец XIX - начало XX века), в России малопопулярное, но актуальное для Беларуси, например.

До революции документом была церковная метрика, а дальше - как письмоводитель зафиксирует.

Об имени хорошо рассказывает [**Википедия**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F),  о современных отчествах - [**Грамота.ру**](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/info/lop/names/).

Comment: *...надарили подарков с такой гравировкой: Арсеновичу (что единственно верно), Арсеньевичу и даже Арсентьевичу,*  - это говорит только о не слишком большом уважении дарителей, не удосужившихся посмотреть правильный вариант. Но тут дело такое, что часто встречается, что человек предпочитает в быту числиться под другим именем, отличным от того, что в документах. Иногда это путает окружающих. Ну вот был, к примеру у кого-то знакомый Арсен, который по паспорту Арсентий. Чем не вариант? Ну вот этот знакомый и начал  всех подряд Арсенов считать Арсентиями.

Comment: Спасибо, Галина! У Вас во фразе "Моего деда звали Арсен, а в батюшкин юбилей ему..." звучит так, как будто деду надарили подарков, хотя по смыслу и понятно, что отцу.

Comment: Тёмыч, я тоже об это дело было споткнулась, но ввиду раннего часа простила себе. Думала, что отчество уберёт путаницу. Щас подумаю, как красиво выпутаться...

Answer (score 2):

> Как вы считаете, действительно правильно делать это различие?

Да. В официальных документах - как минимум. Может потому, что меня так приучили, может потому, что объективные причины до сих пор есть. Понимаете, даже сейчас, а может именно сейчас, в век компьютерной обработки информации, пустяковое различие в документах создаст массу проблем одному, или, наоборот, решит все проблемы, если документы разных лиц. Не буду углублять, примеры сами легко найдутся.

И потом такой еще момент. Коли русский язык различает эти имена и отчества, зачем идти ему наперекор, демонстрируя свою безграмотность?

*Другие ответы пока не читал, так что если кого задел - это "не адресно". Вот сейчас ознакомлюсь, интересно, что тут можно нагородить по такому вопросу*.

Comment: Спасибо, behemothus!

Answer (score 0):

Если в прошлом была причина различать эти имена, по той же логике следует различать и отчества. 
В паспорте скорее всего писали так, как получатель паспорта просил записать.

Comment: Да, но то и интересно, существовали ли одновременно оба имени в качестве полных и действительно ли, когда были Захарии, отчество было именно таким, как написано. Источнику, конечно, хочется доверять, но маленькие неточности могут встретиться и в хорошем справочнике (или ещё чём-то).Или могут быть нюансы, которые уже не получается указать в этих рамках.

Comment: Захар - упрощённая форма библейского имени Захария. Это однозначно одно и то же имя. Почему одновременно существовали обе формы - другой вопрос. Захария правильнее но Захар звучит более мужественно :)

Comment: В упомянутой "логике" есть и практический смысл: возможность без дополнительных изысканий восстановить верный вариант (из трёх возможных) имени родителя. Для меня написание "Захарьевич" указывает на имя Захарий (ср. Евгеньевич - Евгений), а "Захариевич" - на имя Захария.

Comment: @ddbug "В паспорте, скорее всего, писали так, как получатель паспорта просил записать."  В паспорте писали так, как было записано в первичном документе. Чаще всего, очевидно, это была метрическая выписка.